# All headers not displaying

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, html-pdf, node-html-pdf

I am using html-pdf library to save html table into pdf file,file is saving but i am not getting all headers in file.If more headers in table row then all all column not displaying

Here is my backend code

```
var fs = require('fs');
var pdf = require('html-pdf');
var options = { format: 'Letter' };
 var htmldata = ' <div class="uk-grid" data-uk-grid-margin style="margin-top: 12px;"><div class="uk-width-medium-1-1" style="overflow-x: scroll;"><table class="uk-table uk-table-striped uk-table-hover" id="table1">'+
                            '<thead style="display: table-row-group;">'+
                                '<tr style="background:#3399ff;">'+
                                    '<th>Customer </th>'+
                                    '<th>Site ID1</th>'+
                                    '<th>Site Name1</th>'+
                                    '<th>Customer2</th>'+
                                     '<th>Site ID2</th>'+
                                    '<th>Site Name2</th>'+
                                     '<th>Site ID3</th>'+
                                    '<th>Site Name3</th>'+
                                     '<th>Site ID4</th>'+
                                    '<th>Site Name4</th>'+
                                     '<th>Site ID5</th>'+
                                    '<th>Site Name5</th>'+
                                     '<th>Site ID6</th>'+
                                    '<th>Site Name6</th>'+
                                     '<th>Site ID7</th>'+
                                    '<th>Site Name7</th>'+
                                     '<th>Site ID8</th>'+
                                    '<th>Site Name8</th>'+
                                     '<th>Site ID9</th>'+
                                    '<th>Site Name9</th>'+
                                    '<th>Site Name10</th>'+
                                    '<th>Site Name10</th>'+
                                    '<th>Site Name11</th>'+
                                    '<th>Site Name11</th>'+
                                '</tr>'+
                            '</thead><tbody ></tbody></table></div></div>';
                           pdf.create(htmldata, options).toFile('./businesscard.pdf', function(err, res) {
                           if (err) return console.log(err);
                                console.log(res); // { filename: '/app/businesscard.pdf' }
                          });
```

Answer (score 0):

Issue is with the Paper type and number of columns that you are adding.

Columns are getting added but your paper options are not letting them render in PDF.

Try setting few paper related option in your option variable.

```
  // Papersize Options: http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/property/paper-size.html
  "height": "10.5in",        // allowed units: mm, cm, in, px
  "width": "8in",            // allowed units: mm, cm, in, px
  - or -
  "format": "Letter",        // allowed units: A3, A4, A5, Legal, Letter, Tabloid
  "orientation": "portrait", // portrait or landscape

  // Page options
  "border": "0",             // default is 0, units: mm, cm, in, px
  - or -
  "border": {
    "top": "2in",            // default is 0, units: mm, cm, in, px
    "right": "1in",
    "bottom": "2in",
    "left": "1.5in"
  },
```

More options are [here](https://github.com/marcbachmann/node-html-pdf)